# Double integral with a product of dilog $\int _0^1\int _0^1\text{Li}_2(x y) \text{Li}_2((1-y) x)\ dx \ dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, polylogarithm

One of the integrals I came across these days (during my studies) is $$\int _0^1\int _0^1\text{Li}_2(x y) \text{Li}_2((1-y) x) \ dx \ dy$$ 
that can be turned into a series, or can be approached by using the integration by parts, but these
ways do not look like as a promising way to go, or I might be wrong. I would like to know  your vision 
on these integrals, not asking for full solutions, just feel comfortable to share ideas that is the thing I'm most interested in. I'm looking forward to your ideas!

And one more thing, *Mathematica* shows that

$$\int \text{Li}_2(x y) \text{Li}_2((1-y) x) \, dx$$

$$=\frac{\log \left(\frac{2 y-1}{(x (y-1)+1) y}\right) \log ^2\left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{2 (y-1) y}+\frac{\log (x-x y) \log ^2\left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{2 (y-1) y}-\frac{\log \left(\frac{x (2 y-1)}{x (y-1)+1}\right) \log ^2\left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{2 (y-1) y}+\frac{\log (x y) \log (1-x y) \log \left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{(y-1) (x y-1)}{(x (y-1)+1) y}\right) \log \left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{\text{Li}_2(1-x y) \log \left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{(y-1) y}-\frac{\log (1-x y) \log (x-x y) \log \left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{(y-1) y}-\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{(y-1) y}-\frac{\text{Li}_2(x (y-1)+1) \log \left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{6 x y}{y-1}+\frac{3 x \log (x (y-1)+1)}{y-1}+\frac{2 \log (x (y-1)+1) \log \left(-\frac{(y-1) (x y-1)}{2 y-1}\right)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{2 x y \log (x (y-1)+1) \log (1-x y)}{y-1}+\frac{\log (x (y-1)+1) \log (x y) \log (1-x y)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{2 \log \left(\frac{(x (y-1)+1) y}{2 y-1}\right) \log (1-x y)}{y-1}+\frac{3 x \log (1-x y)}{y-1}+\frac{3 \log (1-x y)}{y-1}+\frac{\log ^2(1-x y) \log (x-x y)}{2 (y-1) y}+\frac{\log (1-x y) \text{Li}_2(x (y-1)+1)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{x y \log (x (y-1)+1) \text{Li}_2(x y)}{y-1}+\frac{\log (x (y-1)+1) \text{Li}_2(x y)}{y-1}+\frac{x \text{Li}_2(x y)}{y-1}+\frac{2 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{(x (y-1)+1) y}{2 y-1}\right)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{2 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{(y-1) (1-x y)}{2 y-1}\right)}{y-1}+\frac{\log (x (y-1)+1) \text{Li}_2(1-x y)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{x y \log (1-x y) \text{Li}_2(x-x y)}{y-1}+\frac{\log (1-x y) \text{Li}_2(x-x y)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{x y \text{Li}_2(x y) \text{Li}_2(x-x y)}{y-1}+\frac{x \text{Li}_2(x-x y)}{y-1}+\frac{\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1-x y}{x (y-1)+1}\right)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{6 x}{y-1}-\frac{3 x y \log (x (y-1)+1)}{y-1}-\frac{3 \log (x (y-1)+1)}{y-1}-\frac{2 \log (x (y-1)+1) \log \left(-\frac{(y-1) (x y-1)}{2 y-1}\right)}{y-1}-\frac{3 x y \log (1-x y)}{y-1}-\frac{2 x \log (x (y-1)+1) \log (1-x y)}{y-1}-\frac{x y \text{Li}_2(x y)}{y-1}-\frac{x \log (x (y-1)+1) \text{Li}_2(x y)}{y-1}-\frac{2 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{(x (y-1)+1) y}{2 y-1}\right)}{y-1}-\frac{x y \text{Li}_2(x-x y)}{y-1}-\frac{x \log (1-x y) \text{Li}_2(x-x y)}{y-1}-\frac{\log (1-x y) \text{Li}_2(x-x y)}{y-1}-\frac{x \text{Li}_2(x y) \text{Li}_2(x-x y)}{y-1}-\frac{3 \log (1-x y)}{(y-1) y}-\frac{\text{Li}_3(x (y-1)+1)}{(y-1) y}-\frac{\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{(y-1) (x y-1)}{(x (y-1)+1) y}\right)}{(y-1) y}-\frac{\text{Li}_3(1-x y)}{(y-1) y}+\frac{2}{(y-1) y}-\frac{\log (x y) \log ^2(1-x y)}{2 (y-1) y}.$$

Comment: You have a bad habit of writing terribly interesting questions about polylogarithms without tagging them as such, with the result that I can never find them again in the vast ocean of "integration" tags. I have decided it's high time I fixed that. ;)

Comment: @DavidH hehe, OK, I'll be careful about tagging them properly since now. :-)

Comment: Are you at all familiar with the Nielsen generalized polylogarithm? I'm currently attempting a response that makes heavy use of them, and I'm trying to decide how much background I should include on these functions. The chief advantage of these functions here is MUCH tidier anti-derivative than the unholy mess you mentioned above.

Comment: @DavidH I think I have created some problems that involve the use of the Nielsen generalized polylogarithm. You can come up with any knowledge, and if there is something I don't know, I learn immediately. No concern at all.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(xy\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\left(1-y\right)\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(w\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x-w\right)}}{x};~~~\small{\left[xy=w\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\int_{w}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(w\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x-w\right)}}{x}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(w\right)}\int_{w}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x-w\right)}}{x}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(w\right)}\int_{0}^{1-w}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(v\right)}}{w+v};~~~\small{\left[x-w=v\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(w\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\left(1-w\right)\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\left(1-w\right)u\right)}}{w+\left(1-w\right)u};~~~\small{\left[\frac{v}{1-w}=u\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\left(\frac{1-w}{w}\right)\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(w\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\left(1-w\right)u\right)}}{1+\left(\frac{1-w}{w}\right)u}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-t\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(tu\right)}}{1+\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)u};~~~\small{\left[1-w=t\right]}\\
&=:\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-t\right)}\,G{\left(t\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

The function $G{(t)}$ is evaluated below.

For $0<a\le1\land0<b$,

$$\begin{align}
J{\left(a,b\right)}
&:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(ax\right)}}{1+bx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1+bx\right)}}{b}\left[-\frac{\ln{\left(1-ax\right)}}{x}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x;~~~\small{IBPs}\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1-ax\right)}\ln{\left(1+bx\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\small{\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-ax\right)}+\ln^{2}{\left(1+bx\right)}-\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{1-ax}{1+bx}\right)}}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-ax\right)}}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1+bx\right)}}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{1-ax}{1+bx}\right)}}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1}{2b}\int_{1}^{\frac{1-a}{1+b}}\frac{\left(a+by\right)\ln^{2}{\left(y\right)}}{\left(1-y\right)}\cdot\frac{(-1)\left(a+b\right)}{\left(a+by\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{\left[\frac{1-ax}{1+bx}=y\right]}\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1}{2b}\int_{\frac{1-a}{1+b}}^{1}\frac{\left(a+b\right)\ln^{2}{\left(y\right)}}{\left(1-y\right)\left(a+by\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1}{2b}\int_{\frac{1-a}{1+b}}^{1}\left[\frac{1}{1-y}+\frac{b}{a+by}\right]\ln^{2}{\left(y\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1}{2b}\int_{\frac{1-a}{1+b}}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(y\right)}}{1-y}\,\mathrm{d}y-\frac12\int_{\frac{1-a}{1+b}}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(y\right)}}{a+by}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{\gamma}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-z\right)}}{2z}\,\mathrm{d}z;~~~\small{\left[1-y=z,~\gamma:=\frac{a+b}{1+b}\right]}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{\lambda}^{\mu}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{w}{\mu}\right)}}{b\left(1+w\right)}\,\mathrm{d}w;~~~\small{\left[\frac{by}{a}=w,~\lambda:=\frac{\left(1-a\right)b}{a\left(1+b\right)},~\mu:=\frac{b}{a}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}-\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(\gamma\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\mu\right)}}{2b}\int_{\lambda}^{\mu}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{1+w}+\frac{\ln{\left(\mu\right)}}{b}\int_{\lambda}^{\mu}\frac{\ln{\left(w\right)}}{1+w}\,\mathrm{d}w\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1}{2b}\int_{\lambda}^{\mu}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(w\right)}}{1+w}\,\mathrm{d}w\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}-\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(\gamma\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\mu\right)}}{2b}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\mu}{1+\lambda}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\ln{\left(\mu\right)}}{b}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-w\right)}+\ln{\left(w\right)}\ln{\left(1+w\right)}\right]_{w=\lambda}^{w=\mu}\\
&~~~~~\small{-\frac{1}{b}\left[\frac16\ln{\left(\frac{w^3}{1+w}\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(1+w\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(-w\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{1}{1+w}\right)}\right]_{w=\lambda}^{w=\mu}}\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}-\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(\gamma\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}\ln{\left(1+b\right)}}{2b}\\
&~~~~~\small{+\frac{\ln{\left(\mu\right)}}{b}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\mu\right)}+\ln{\left(\mu\right)}\ln{\left(1+\mu\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\lambda\right)}-\ln{\left(\lambda\right)}\ln{\left(1+\lambda\right)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~\small{+\frac{1}{b}\left[S_{1,2}{\left(-\mu\right)}+S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(-\lambda\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\right)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~\small{-\frac{1}{6b}\left[\ln{\left(\frac{\mu^3}{1+\mu}\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(1+\mu\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{\lambda^3}{1+\lambda}\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(1+\lambda\right)}\right]}\\
\end{align}$$

and finally,

$$\begin{align}
&=\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}-\frac{1}{b}S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{1+b}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}\ln{\left(1+b\right)}}{2b}+\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}}{b}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{\left(a-1\right)b}{a\left(b+1\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}}{b}\left[\ln{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}\ln{\left(1+b\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{1-a}{1+b}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{a+b}{a\left(1+b\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~\small{+\frac{1}{b}\left[S_{1,2}{\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)}+S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{\left(a-1\right)b}{a\left(b+1\right)}\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{a\left(1+b\right)}{a+b}\right)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{6b}\left[\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-a\right)^3}{\left(1+b\right)^2}\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{a\left(1+b\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~\small{+\frac{1}{6b}\left[\ln{\left(\frac{b^3}{a^2\left(a+b\right)}\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{a\left(1+b\right)}\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{b^3}{a^2\left(a+b\right)}\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right)}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{b}\left[S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+S_{1,2}{\left(-b\right)}+S_{1,2}{\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{1+b}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{b}\left[S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{\left(a-1\right)b}{a\left(b+1\right)}\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{a\left(1+b\right)}{a+b}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}}{b}+\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}}{b}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{\left(a-1\right)b}{a\left(b+1\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}\ln{\left(1+b\right)}}{2b}-\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}}{b}\ln{\left(\frac{1-a}{1+b}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{a+b}{a\left(1+b\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{6b}\left[\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-a\right)^3}{\left(1+b\right)^2}\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{a\left(1+b\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{b^3}{a^2\left(a+b\right)}\right)}}{6b}\left[\ln{\left(1+b\right)}-2\ln{\left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right)}\right]\\
\end{align}$$

$\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{a\left(1+b\right)}\right)}=\ln^{2}{\left(1+b\right)}+\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right)}-2\ln{\left(1+b\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right)}$

Thus, for $0<a\le1$ we have:

$$\begin{align}
G{\left(a\right)}
&:=J{\left(a,\frac{a}{1-a}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1-a}{a}\left[S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right)}+S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{1}{a-1}\right)}+S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{1-a}{2-a}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{a-1}{a}\left[S_{1,2}{\left(a-1\right)}+S_{1,2}{\left(\frac{1}{2-a}\right)}+S_{1,2}{\left(a(2-a)\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\left(a-1\right)\ln{\left(1-a\right)}}{a}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{1}{a-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a-1\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~\small{+\frac{\left(a-1\right)\ln{\left(1-a\right)}\left[\ln^{2}{\left(1-a\right)}-9\ln{\left(1-a\right)}\ln{\left(2-a\right)}-3\ln^{2}{\left(2-a\right)}\right]}{6a}}\\
&=\frac{1-a}{a}\left[2\,S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(a(2-a)\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\left(1-a\right)\ln{\left(1-a\right)}}{a}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a-1\right)}-\zeta{(2)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(1-a\right)}{a}\left[\ln^{2}{\left(1-a\right)}\ln{\left(2-a\right)}\right].\\
\end{align}$$

And thus,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1-x}{x}\,G{\left(1-x\right)}
&=2\,S_{1,2}{\left(1-x\right)}-S_{1,2}{\left(1-x^2\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\ln{\left(x\right)}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-x\right)}-\zeta{(2)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+2\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1+x\right)}\\
&=\small{-2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}+2\ln{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}+\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}+2\,\zeta{(3)}}\\
&~~~~~\small{+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x^2\right)}-\ln{\left(x^2\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x^2\right)}-\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(x^2\right)}\ln{\left(1-x^2\right)}-\zeta{(3)}}\\
&~~~~~-\ln{\left(x\right)}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-x\right)}-\zeta{(2)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+2\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1+x\right)}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x^2\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\ln{\left(x\right)}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x^2\right)}-\zeta{(2)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}+\zeta{(3)}\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}+4\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-x\right)}-\ln{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\ln{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-x\right)}+\zeta{(3)}\\
\end{align}$$

Now we can reduce the desired double integral to a sum of  single integrals as follows:

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-t\right)}\,G{\left(t\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}\,G{\left(1-x\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

The rest of the evaluation should be straightforward, so I leave the obtaining of a final value as an exercise for the fearless reader. ;)

Comment: An endless amount of stuff (+1). :-)

Comment: this is crazy (+1)

Answer (score 2):

By using the Euler Beta function it is straightforward to check that:

$$ I = \sum_{m\geq 1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^2 n^2 (m+n+1)^2 \binom{m+n}{m} }\tag{1}$$
but since:
$$ \sum_{h=1}^{s-1}\frac{1}{h^2(s-h)^2\binom{s}{h}}=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{h=1}^{s-1}\frac{\Gamma(h)\Gamma(s-h)}{h(s-h) \Gamma(s)}=\frac{2}{s^2}\sum_{h=1}^{s-1}\frac{B(h,s-h)}{h}\tag{2}$$
we have:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{s=2}^{+\infty}\frac{2(1-x)^s}{s^2(s+1)^2}\sum_{h=1}^{s-1}\frac{\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^h}{h}\,\frac{dx}{x(1-x)}\tag{3}$$
or:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{s=2}^{+\infty}\frac{2}{s^2(s+1)^2(1+u)^{s+2}}\sum_{h=1}^{s-1}\frac{u^h}{h}\left(2+u+\frac{1}{u}\right)\,du\tag{4}$$
Integration by parts, together with a rearrangement of the innermost sum, should make things easier to handle now.

Comment: (+1) interesting option. Using the variable change in the double series is proving to be a good idea in many multiple series. I'd be curious about a nice way of handling the last form of $I$ - I'll check what you suggested.